The loss value equals to NaN during training, how can I fix this?
I am fine tuning FasterRCNN model for object detection project. I am using object detection tutorial of Pytorch from the link text.
The dataset is custom and in coco format. You can download the dataset from here text. I used labelImg to label this dataset in VOC format. Then convert it to the coca format via pylabel.
The command line arguments I have given are;
"--data-path", "..\\Dataset\\data_set_coco",
"--model", "fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn",
"batch-size", "16",
"epochs", "100",
"print-freq", "5",
"output-dir", ".\\results",
"backend", "tensor",
"weights-backbone", "ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1",
"use-v2",

My aim is doing only object detection, not segmentation. This is why I used "use-v2" argument.
For the first epoch, output is this;
Epoch: [0]  [ 0/23]  eta: 0:27:58  lr: 0.000928  loss: 5.2509 (5.2509)  loss_classifier: 4.5420 (4.5420)  loss_box_reg: 0.0006 (0.0006)  loss_objectness: 0.6790 (0.6790)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0293 (0.0293)  time: 72.9583  data: 15.0346  max mem: 18916
Epoch: [0]  [20/23]  eta: 0:02:34  lr: 0.019092  loss: 0.4284 (1.5884)  loss_classifier: 0.2211 (1.2283)  loss_box_reg: 0.0296 (0.0344)  loss_objectness: 0.0589 (0.2585)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0376 (0.0672)  time: 50.4280  data: 0.0239  max mem: 19053
Epoch: [0]  [22/23]  eta: 0:00:50  lr: 0.020000  loss: 0.3843 (1.4968)  loss_classifier: 0.1955 (1.1559)  loss_box_reg: 0.0446 (0.0377)  loss_objectness: 0.0483 (0.2396)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0316 (0.0635)  time: 49.9681  data: 0.0226  max mem: 19053
Epoch: [0] Total time: 0:19:30 (50.8758 s / it)
Test:  [ 0/32]  eta: 0:08:09  model_time: 0.7523 (0.7523)  evaluator_time: 0.0042 (0.0042)  time: 15.2950  data: 14.5345  max mem: 19053
Test:  [31/32]  eta: 0:00:01  model_time: 0.5700 (0.5871)  evaluator_time: 0.0010 (0.0007)  time: 0.6016  data: 0.0012  max mem: 19053
Test: Total time: 0:00:34 (1.0793 s / it)
Averaged stats: model_time: 0.5700 (0.5871)  evaluator_time: 0.0010 (0.0007)
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=0.01s).
IoU metric: bbox
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000

Then in the second epoch, it prints the first loss then the code throws exception.
Epoch: [1]  [ 0/23]  eta: 0:26:27  lr: 0.020000  loss: 0.8838 (0.8838)  loss_classifier: 0.7125 (0.7125)  loss_box_reg: 0.0614 (0.0614)  loss_objectness: 0.0181 (0.0181)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0918 (0.0918)  time: 69.0171  data: 14.8666  max mem: 19053  
Loss is nan, stopping training
{'loss_classifier': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>), 'loss_box_reg': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>), 'loss_objectness': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward0>), 'loss_rpn_box_reg': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)}

I restarted the code, and encoutered with the same results. I dont recall whether values of losses were the same or not. But again in the second epoch, the loss function came as NaN.
I would appreciate any help.

Did you check the data format consistency like n_classes, null classes and value range? You are now using an official code and these are not seems to be wrong.

@ZombaSY thank you for your comment. The class number was 91 in the code but in my case it should be 5. I updated number of classes. This does not solve the problem however. The thing that solved my problem was decreasing learning rate to 0.002 from 0.02. Now the model can be trained.
